# Regex with String Split

Tags: java, regex, split

I'm using a regular expression to split a given arithmetic string into their own indexes in an array.

```
String stringM = "variable1 = 1 + 2 * (4 * (3 + 2) / 6)";
String str = stringM.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
String[] result = str.split("(?<=[-+*/%=()])|(?=[-+*/%=()])");
```

This would result in

```
[variable1, =, 1, +, 2, *, (, 4, *, (, 3, +, 2, ), /, 6, )]
```

However, I'm also trying to account for certain python specific things like ** and //. I can't quite figure out how to change my split to account for up to 2 multiplications and division signs. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be fantastic.

Comment: Just scan for `\*\*|//`?

Comment: You can use [`\w+|[^\s\w]+`](https://regex101.com/r/Jr2gk6/1)